# Why add members to Constructor function and not to Prototype?

Tags: javascript

Why would you add members to a constructor function and not the prototype?

```
function foo() {
}

foo.prototype.isThereSayShoeSize = function() {
    console.log(this.sayShoeSize);
}

foo.fooObject = {num: 100, shoeSize: 43}

foo.sayShoeSize = function() {
    console.log(foo.fooObject.shoeSize)
}

var myFoo = new foo();

console.log(myFoo.sayShoeSize);  //undefined
myFoo.isThereSayShoeSize()       //undefined
```

The members are not owned by instances nor shared amongst instances. So these members can not be accessed through an `instance.member` syntax nor with the `this` keyword within an instance.

So it would seem that members added to the constructor function have no relation to the type.

I can think of only two possible explainations. 1 to conserve namespace space by grouping these memebers with the type, which doesn't make a lot of sense if they aren't related to the type. 2 They are static members which can be accessed without an instance of the type. This makes sense if there are objects of another type that wish to consume these members. But in the context which I have seen this pattern these members are only used by instances of the type they are attached to. So in that context they are relevant to the type and only consumed by instances of the type, so why not put them in the prototype?

I am a little confused by this as you can probably tell. I think perhaps this pattern of adding members to the constructor is just inappropriate in the context I have seen it, and the members should have been added to the prototype. But would you call these members static? And would having members that are consumable by both the type they are attached to and other types be the main use for this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
function foo() {};
foo.fooObject = {num: 100, shoeSize: 43};
```

it is similar to setting a class variable in the C++ world that is available to all instances as `foo.fooObject` and the same for all instances.  It's a namespaced way of setting global variables.  As you point out they are not instance variables, so this technique should only be used when a scoped global variable is the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, would you say the main reason a scoped variable would be desired would be to avoid namespace conflicts? Also I see how it is a global variable but surely if it was on the prototype it would be global also unless it was overwritten in an instance?

Comment: Mostly for namespacing cleanliness.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially **static** methods and properties.

Why? How?

Let's forget `foo` is meant to be used as constructor. The methods added to `foo` are members of the `foo()` function (functions are objects too, so they can have methods as well.)

So, to invoke these methods, you simply have to access members of the `foo` function. That means either

```
foo.sayShoeSize();
```

or

```
foo['sayShoeSize']();
```

At this point, you didn't have to call `foo` using the `new` operator. And since there are not part of the prototype chain, an object created using `foo` as a constructor will not *inherit* those methods and properties. That means:

```
var myFoo = new foo();

console.log(typeof myFoo.sayShowSize); // undefined
```

All in all, functions defined on a constructor directly should not use or rely on `this`. In other words, `this` will be bound to the global object (that is unless they are invoked using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), of course.)